# Rendering MHT on Iphone

Tags: iphone, reporting-services, mhtml

I have seen a few threads about SSRS reports not displaying correctly on IPhones.

I have one display as best as possible on a phone, however the attachment icon floats at the bottom.  I believe this is because the native I phone e-mail app doesn't render MHT properly and can't detect the end of the e-mail body.

I have tried to send the SSRS report through the subscription as html 4.0 also but still no luck.  Seen something about someone having to force their report to run in strict mode, not sure what that is but that was from a custom report app.

Has anyone come across this issue and resolved it to send SSRS reports to an phone native client and display with that attachment app?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time trying to get subscription attachments to open (and show data) on iphone and ipad, using native and 3rd party apps and I've always unresolvable issues.  (basically, what SSRS saves *is not* what  word or excel saves)   But one of my clients downloaded outlook for IOS (free!) which has been out for a few months and can suddenly view all of those attachments.    good luck.

Comment: Thanks,  yes the issues I have seen only seem to be on the native IOS e-mail client.  A lot of the company phones do have them but I have been asked to look at getting them working for the ios client but doesn't seem possible,

Answer (score 0):

I know is old thread, but I just solved just replace the style inside a html table `overflow:auto` to `overflow:visible` before to send the emails. Now it renders correctly in native IOS email client.